# How can I get my JSON to return in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building out an API using Node for the first time but a little stuck on something.

I have the following files:

My routes, **routes/index.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const transactionsController = require('../controllers/transactionsController');
const ordersController = require('../controllers/ordersController');
const ordersCountController = require('../controllers/ordersCountController');

router.get('/transactions', transactionsController);
router.get('/orders', ordersController);
router.get('/orders_count', ordersCountController);

module.exports = router;
```

My controllers, **controllers/ordersCountController.js**:

```
const ordersCountService = require('../services/ordersCountService');

const ordersCountController = async () => {

    try {
        const data = await ordersCountService();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

module.exports = ordersCountController;
```

My service to fetch from an external API, **services/ordersCountService.js**:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const ordersCountService = async () => {
    const URL = ....;

    const settings = { method: 'Get'};
    const res = await fetch(URL, settings);
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Unable to retrieve data');
    return await res.json();
}

module.exports = ordersCountService;
```

How can I pass the JSON through to the browser?

I have been trying a few things - you'll notice the return data; - but I can't figure out how to return the JSON so that it's displayed in the browser when someone visits ourdomain.com/api/orders_count.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here? I am still new to JS so sorry if I am missing something completely obvious here.

Thank you all for your time. If there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, `ordersCountService` should have 2 parameters: `req` and `res`:

> - The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, and HTTP headers.
> - The res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

In this case, your controller should be:

```
const ordersCountController = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const data = await ordersCountService();
        console.log(data);
        res.json({data})
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Save it, and open the express server, and type the route url in the browser, you would see the json format.
You could find more information about Express in this article.
[Express Explained with Examples - Installation, Routing, Middleware, and More](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/express-explained-with-examples-installation-routing-middleware-and-more/)